# Get the latest index of a certain form in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am periodically training an anomaly detection model and I am saving it in `elasticsearch` index of the form `'anomaly_detection_model-' + date_model_trained`. This means that I am ending up with indices of the form: `anomaly_detection_model-31.08.2022`, `anomaly_detection_model-29.08.2022`, `anomaly_detection_model-27.08.2022`, etc. I need to be able to get access to the latest model at real-time in order to make the predictions without knowing what is the date that this model was trained. Do you have any ideas of how this could be possible?

Answer (score 0):

if you need to access to the last created index try this:

```
GET /_cat/indices?pretty&s=creation.date:desc
```

Comment: The thing is that the elastisearch include also another indices inside, so the latest created index might not be related with the anomaly detection.

Comment: `GET /_cat/indices/anomaly_detection_model-*?pretty&s=creation.date:desc` will work